# Filename in zip file is too long java

Tags: java, file, io

I have an application that take a zip file as input in Java.
My application would decompress the zip file and inside the zip file there are some file contains filename exceeds 256 chars

Could I modify the filename of a file in zip without decompression

OS : linux/mac

Comment: Well, not so much OS as [filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits)

Comment: @Thilo Assuming he's talking about _full path_ I'd guess it's Windows. If it's really a filename, 255 is a maximum for quite a few file systems.

Comment: One possible reason is the zip file is created in Windows (NTFS) or MacOS (HFS+) and file name in it contains multibytes characters, and your application is running in Linux with ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem. To test, zip the following file in Windows/MacOS, and unzip in Linux: `zip test.zip １２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５` (255 characters, 500 bytes)

Comment: I just have the same problem. In fact, this is **not** related to the underlying file system. This is a problem in Java, especially `private static native long ZipFile::open`. In my case (NTFS) the file system easily supports long file name. Alas, even opening such "long filename" file throws the exception "Path too long" (funny, btw, with no more details!). Note we're not talking yet about entries __inside__ the ZIP file. Opening the file fails already.

Comment: EDIT: Bug JDK-6374379. Maybe the JDK i'm currently using does not yet have the fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more of a limitation of the file system used, than the OS itself.

You can only change this by formatting the drives to a different file system that supports longer file names.

Why you would need a file name that is couple of miles long is beyond me. But only advise I can give is, try to shorten the file name.

**::EDIT::**

Since you updated your question. Here's the correct answer. :)

Typically, your approach is correct. Although if your zip contains longer filenames, you can truncate them. (Take the first, 250, ignore the rest. Now, you may have duplicate filenames. Add a number at the end coz you got 5 chars left)
Another option is to ask the user to enter a new file name.

It is possible to edit the zip file itself, as long as you know how it is structured .etc.

I'm not aware that Java built-in APIs allow editing zip files. Although a while back, I came across this library names DotNetZip for Microsoft.NET which allows all the typical functionality plus editing the entries inside a zip file, encryption, passwords .etc. (it is awesome btw)

Look for a similar library for Java.

Comment: you were faster than me:) I would even cite an extreme case in which a Windows user would try to copy a file from NTFS to the old DOS FAT system that only supported 8+3 filenames.

Answer (score 0):

If the user were supplying a filename for a file to be created, I think you'd just have to ask for a shorter name, short enough to avoid throwing this exception.

But it sounds like this is the name of an existing file to be read from; in that case, if the system (file or operating; either way, something you can't control) is saying its not a valid filename, how could you expect to be able to read from it?